# When I try to cancel DownloadFileTaskAsync my WPF application crash and shut down

Tags: c#, wpf, download, webclient

I'm making a WPF application where I use WebClient to download a file from a webserver. When I download file my WPF application crash and shut down when I'm trying to cancel the downloading. It is not always this happens. Sometimes it success to cancel, but for the most it doesn't I have no clue it behaves like this. Thank you

```
  public async Task DownloadProtocol(int torrentId, string address, string location)
    {
        Uri Uri = new Uri(address);
        try
        {
            using (client = new WebClient())
            {

                sw.Start();
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, e) =>
                {
                    var thisGame = MainWindow._items.Find(item => item.Id == torrentId);
                    PercentageDone = (e.BytesReceived / TotalSize) * 100;

                    thisGame.Progress = (int)SizeReceived + (int)PercentageDone;

                    Console.Write("\r {0} ", PercentageDone);

                };

                client.DownloadFileCompleted += (o, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Cancelled == true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Download has been canceled.");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");
                        SizeReceived += PercentageDone;
                    }

                    client.Dispose();
                };

                await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(Uri, location);
            }
        }
        catch(WebException ex)
        {
            Log.Logger("Download error ", ex);
        }

    }
```

Cancel function:

```
    public void Cancel()
    {
        if(client != null)
        {
            client.CancelAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Provide a clean example demonstrating the issue without using your classes

Comment: I get this exception when i cancel a download @netaholic: Download error System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsReadCallbackState(DownloadBitsState state, IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF applications usually crash because of unhandled exceptions. In a WPF application, you can log and/or handle them by subscribing to these events in your App class constructor (see the code below).

You should also remove the `client.Dispose` call from your `DownloadFileCompleted` handler, since `client` will be disposed by the using block, and the instance may not have finished its other work (e.g. sending the Task completion) before your handler is called.

```
public partial class App : System.Windows.Application
{
    public App()
    {
        this.DispatcherUnhandledException += this.OnDispatcherUnhandledException;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += this.OnAppDomainUnhandledException;
        System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += this.OnUnobservedTaskException;
    }

    private void OnAppDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Log.Logger("AppDomainUnhandledException", e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
    }

    private void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        Log.Logger("DispatcherUnhandled: ", e.Exception);
    }

    private void OnUnobservedTaskException(object sender, System.Threading.Tasks.UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.SetObserved();
        Log.Logger("UnobservedTaskException", e.Exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @JoelV.Earnest-DeYoung, but how do I subscriibe these events?

Comment: Look at the code in my answer. The three lines in the App constructor subscribe to unhandled WPF Dispatcher exceptions, unhandled AppDomain exception, and unhandled Task exceptions, respectively. The code also includes sample methods for handling each of these three exception types. Here I log the exceptions, but otherwise ignore them. In production code, it's usually better to handle unexpected exceptions some way other than ignoring them.

Comment: Sorry if you already answered this, but do I need to make a new object of App in my catch? I'm new with C#, I'm use to C and C++ @JoelV.Earnest-DeYoung

Comment: If you look in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer, your WPF project should have a file called App.xaml with an arrow that expands to show App.xaml.cs. The App class C# code is in App.xaml.cs, and that's where you'd add the constructor and exception handling methods.